# webcam not working on lenovo x230

Tags: webcam, lenovo, thinkpad

I've got Ubuntu 12.04 running on my lenovo X230.  I can't get the integrated webcam working with Google Talk plugin or with Cheese.

Comment: What is the output of the following command: `lsmod | grep uvcvideo`?

Comment: I get a blank return in terminal when I run that command

Comment: no output? - then run as sudo: sudo lsmod | grep uvcvideo

Answer (score 1):

It seems your system is not loading the driver responsible to communicate with the webcam. Try executing this in one terminal

```
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

This should provide no output. If you get any error post it in the comments. Then try to use the webcam (with Cheese, by example).

If this solves your problem, you should add `uvcvideo` to `/etc/modules` file, to force the system to load it at boot time. The content of that file at the end should be

```
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

loop
lp
rtc

uvcvideo
```

Comment: It seems this [post](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/X-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/My-new-2306CTO-X230-ThinkPad-is-missing-the-webcam/td-p/826729) solves the problem.  Lenovo doesn't allow the 3x3 wifi antenna with a camera.  I chose the former but it was nowhere obvious while ordering that this would not allow for a camera.

Comment: This did the trick for me as well.  You should mark this as the answer.

Comment: For Ubutnu 20.04 the issue is not solved. Sad :-(

Answer (score 0):

1. Install tool v4l2ucp (sudo apt-get install v4l2ucp)
2. Reset all values under it (brightness, Contrast, Saturation etc.) which are set to max by default.

Enjoy.

Comment: ...probably nowadays w/ ubuntu 20.04: package v4l2ucp is unable to be located.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. No camera was found.
`lsmod | grep uvcvideo` did show some propper output.
Camera did not work.

Solution was to activate camera on bios!

Here is where I got it running from: https://forums.lenovo.com/topic/findpost/1301/4385387/4385397